# Full version of this mantra I heard in my dream: "Tarune deveem rasa..."

Tags: scripture, gods, mantras, devi, dream

Today (Tuesday, Sept 5th, 2023), I learned a mantra during a dream. When I woke I remembered only part of that mantra from my dream.

This is all I can remember:

> Tarune deveem rasa...

I think that Devi is trying to give/tell me something that may potentially help my current situation. But I was not able to remember the mantra. Does anyone know any more details/know the rest of the mantra?

(I tried googling "tarune deveem rasa" but can not find any mantra like this or similar to this.)